# How do I perform a custom sort on a DataGrid column when ItemsSource == null?

Tags: wpf, sorting, datagrid

How do I implement a custom sort when DataGrid.ItemsSource == null?  I have used DataGrid.Items.Add() to add items incrementally to the DataGrid instead of assigning the ItemsSource, so my ItemsSource always seems to be null. I want to use a sort handler like this one (below) but ((DataGrid)sender).ItemsSource is always null. What to do?

```
public void SortHandler(object sender, DataGridSortingEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridColumn column = e.Column;

        if (column.DisplayIndex == 1)
        {
            IComparer comparer = null;

            //i do some custom checking based on column to get the right comparer
            //i have different comparers for different columns. I also handle the sort direction
            //in my comparer

            // prevent the built-in sort from sorting
            e.Handled = true;

            ListSortDirection direction = (column.SortDirection != ListSortDirection.Ascending) ? ListSortDirection.Ascending : ListSortDirection.Descending;

            //set the sort order on the column
            column.SortDirection = direction;

            //use a ListCollectionView to do the sort.
            ListCollectionView lcv = (ListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(((DataGrid)sender).ItemsSource);                

            //this is my custom sorter it just derives from IComparer and has a few properties
            //you could just apply the comparer but i needed to do a few extra bits and pieces
            comparer = new MySort(direction, column);

            //apply the sort
            lcv.CustomSort = comparer;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Handled = false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The powerful feature of WPF is the binding support, so why not to use it. So, i would suggest you to bind the ItemSource of your dataGrid to an `ObservableCollection` in your class and add the items to this collection.

The benefit you get with the the `ObservableCollection` that it implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` and that way you don't have to worry about UI refresh issue. Items will be updated on your UI as soon as you add item.

Also, you can use `CollectionViewSource`. Refer to this article here - http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=387